# MySql case-sensitive with utf 8 format set system variables

Tags: mysql, postgresql, case-sensitive

I have been trying to get my result as per the case-sensitive condition case.

[image: screen 1]

[image: syatem variable]

I need to set it in this way only since I am using migration wizard to import data from postgres and there is some problem with case-sensitivity. I want mysql to insert data while importing in case-sensitive way.

if there is some other way to overcome problem then please help. utf8_bin is not working.

Comment: I don't understand why you used the 'postgresql' tag...

Comment: as I mentioned I am trying to migrate data from postgres

Comment: Oups sorry, my bad